# Android Realm default database clear

Tags: android, realm

How to clear default realm database in android ? I tried following code but cannot resolve method deleteRealmFile.

**Method 1 :**

```
try {
   Realm.deleteRealmFile(context);
  //Realm file has been deleted.

} catch (Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
  //No Realm file to remove.
}
```

I tried to delete using configuration.

**Method 2 :**

```
try {
     Realm.deleteRealm(realm.getConfiguration());
     //Realm file has been deleted.
} catch (Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
     //No Realm file to remove.
}
```

but is gives the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to delete the file associated with an open Realm. Remember to close() all the instances of the Realm before deleting its file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception described, you have to close all Realm instances which refer to the specific realm file.

This means, if you have called

`Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);`

You have to close the Realm before delete it.

`realm.close();`

And the Realm instances are based on reference counter, so please ensure every `getInstance` has a matched `close`.

This is very important, otherwise memory leak could happen. 
See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances for some examples.

Answer (score 6):

Before `Realm.deleteRealm(realm.getConfiguration());` just add `realm.close()` like below and it works like a charm

```
try {
      realm.close()
      Realm.deleteRealm(realm.getConfiguration());
                //Realm file has been deleted.
} catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                //No Realm file to remove.
}
```

Comment: this is not working not working, throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to delete the file associated with an open Realm. Remember to close() all the instances of the Realm before deleting its file.